# Fourier Transform of $\frac1{\cosh^2(x)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, residue-calculus

How do you take the Fourier transform of
$f(x)= \dfrac{1}{\cosh^2(x)}$, using contour integration? (Where the complex Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is defined to be $\hat{f}(k) = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-ikx}\,dx$).

This is for a complex class so I tried expanding the denominator and calculating a residue by using the rectangular contour that goes from $-\infty$
to $\infty$ along the real axis and $i\pi+\infty$
to $i\pi-\infty$ to close the contour (with vertical sides that go to 0). Therefore, I tried to calculate the residue at $\frac{i\pi}{2}$
of $\dfrac{e^{-ikx}}{e^x + e^{-x}}$ which will be give me the answer, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Which definition of the FT are you using? (There are [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions) popular normalizations.) For example, are you trying to calculate the integral below?$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{ikx}dx}{\frac14(e^x+e^{-x})^2}$$Please edit your preferred convention into the question.

Comment: As for the residue, it's at a second-order pole, so use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles). You'll also need to use L'Hôpital's rule repeatedly viz.$$\lim_{z\to a}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{(z-a)^2f(z)}{g^2(z)}=\frac{f'(a)g'(a)-f(a)g''(a)}{g^{\prime3}(a)}.$$

Comment: One can use the identity $\cosh^2(x)=\frac12 (1+\cosh(2x))$ to arrive at the quality $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{\cosh^2(x)}\,e^{-ikx}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{1+\cosh(x)}\,e^{ikx/2}\,dx$$Now the problem is reduced to evaluating a the residue at a simple pole (i.e., a pole of order one).